# Error with fetch() method

Tags: php, mysql, database, fetch

I am getting the error statement:

> Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in /home/content/26/11794426/html/practice/home.php on line 16

Based off this, I believe that the mysql query isn't making an object. However, I am copying my code directly from a book so I am confused why I'm getting an error. Is it the fetch() part itself or the query?

Also, the database I copied and pasted the sql query into the phpmyadmin so I don't think there is an error there, but I'm not ruling it out.

Any ideas?

```
<?php
require_once('database.php');

// Get category ID
if(!isset($category_id)) {
    $category_id = $_GET['category_id'];
    if (!isset($category_id)) {
        $category_id = 1;
    }
}

// Get name for current category
$query = "SELECT * FROM categories
          WHERE categoryID = $category_id";
$category = $db->query($query);
$category = $category->fetch();
$category_name = $category['categoryName'];

// Get all categories
$query = 'SELECT * FROM categories
          ORDER BY categoryID';
$categories = $db->query($query);

// Get products for selected category
$query = "SELECT * FROM products
          WHERE categoryID = $category_id
          ORDER BY productID";
$products = $db->query($query);

?>
```

this is what my database.php file looks like:

```
<?php

 $dsn = 'mysql:host=guitarshop27.db.11794426.hostedresource.com;dbname = guitarshop27';
 $username = 'changed';
 $password = 'changed';

 try {
     $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
 }catch (PDOException $e) {
     $error_message = $e->getMessage();
     include('database_error.php');
     exit();
     }
  ?>
```

Comment: When that happens, it's likely the query failing

Answer (score 0):

```
$category = $db->query($query);
$categorys = $category->fetch();
$category_name = $categorys['categoryName'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with fetch_assoc();

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM categories
          WHERE categoryID = $category_id";
$category = $db->query($query);
$category = $category->fetch_assoc();
$category_name = $category['categoryName'];
```

But the problem is the database conection. Where is it defined?

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug your Code and also add this add this Code

```
// Get name for current category
$query = "SELECT * FROM categories
          WHERE categoryID = $category_id";
$category = $db->query($query);
echo mysql_nun_rows($category);
$categories = $category->fetch();
$category_name = $categories['categoryName'];
```

if you find still error then check your database connection